# Close button (div contained on) of a modal popup (div) isn't completely shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a problem with the close button of a modal window from [jQuery Modal](http://jquerymodal.com/)

On this example we can see the close button correctly positionned:

[image: ...]

In my local demo I have the following problem:

[image: ...]

I have tried changing the `z-index`, absolute-relative positions, but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modals {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.centered-modal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -o-border-radius: 8px;
  -ms-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  text-align: left;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal a.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5px;
  right: -12.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/NlyAAAAAXNSR…o8lCKWUlg/YtGs7tObunDAZfpDLbfEI15zsEIY3U/x/gHHc/G1zltnAgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Neptune Insurance</title>
  <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;height: 100%;">
  <!-- Link to open the modal -->
  <p><a href="#ex1" onclick="javascript:$('.modal').modal();">Open Modal</a></p>
  <div data-flag="frontload" data-request="modals" class="modals">
    <div class="modal centered-modal car show" style="padding-right: 17px;"><a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close" class="close-modal ">Close</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe there is a conflict between jQueryUI and jQuery Modal CSS styles but I'm not sure. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) settings are hiding content that overflows the modal.
I've commented them out, below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modals {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  /*overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  */
}

.centered-modal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  outline: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -o-border-radius: 8px;
  -ms-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  text-align: left;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal a.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5px;
  right: -12.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/NlyAAAAAXNSR…o8lCKWUlg/YtGs7tObunDAZfpDLbfEI15zsEIY3U/x/gHHc/G1zltnAgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Neptune Insurance</title>
  <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;height: 100%;">
  <!-- Link to open the modal -->
  <p><a href="#ex1" onclick="javascript:$('.modal').modal();">Open Modal</a></p>
  <div data-flag="frontload" data-request="modals" class="modals">
    <div class="modal centered-modal car show" style="padding-right: 17px;"><a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close" class="close-modal ">Close</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fundamentally different from the example on the jquery modal site.  But most importantly you have NO content in your modal, so of course it will appear empty.

Fiddle included below, your code but using the exact example from the website you referenced (with content in the modal).

https://jsfiddle.net/m6puh4w2/3/

```
<p><a href="#ex1" onclick="javascript:$('.modal').modal();">Open Modal</a></p>

<div id="ex1" class="modal">
    <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>
```

If you look at the fiddle code, i've removed some of your strange body classes and attributes, and the extra divs around the modal.  I would start with what I have, and slowly add back in what you need (if any) that I removed until it breaks again. Then you will know why.